# How to retrieve and display information stored in a MongoDB database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently coding a NodeJS server that I'm trying to connect to my MongoDB database, so I'm using `mongoose`. The problem is that after successfully creating an entry in the database, my server can't find it and considers that there's an error.

Here is my " Client " object and my database functions:

`Client.js`

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const clientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    hwid: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    ip: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    timestamp: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
    },
    publicKey: String,
    privateKey: String,
    bitcoinAddress: String,
});

const Client = mongoose.model('Client', clientSchema);

export default Client;
```

`db.js`

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import Client from '../models/Client.js';
import { generateKeyPair } from 'crypto';

export const connectToDatabase = async (databaseURL) => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(databaseURL);
        console.log(`[i] Connected to MongoDB at: ${databaseURL}`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('[!] Error connecting to MongoDB:', error.message);
        process.exit(1);
    }
};

export const disconnectFromDatabase = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.disconnect();
        console.log('[i] Disconnected from MongoDB');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('[!] Error disconnecting from MongoDB:', error.message);
    }
};

export const generateRSAKeys = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        generateKeyPair('rsa', {
            modulusLength: 2048,
            publicKeyEncoding: {
                type: 'spki',
                format: 'pem',
            },
            privateKeyEncoding: {
                type: 'pkcs8',
                format: 'pem',
            },
        }, (err, publicKey, privateKey) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve({ publicKey, privateKey });
            }
        });
    });
};

export const createClient = async (hwid, ip) => {
    try {
        const existingClient = await Client.findOne({ hwid });

        if (!existingClient) {
            const { publicKey, privateKey } = await generateRSAKeys();
            const newClient = new Client({
                hwid,
                ip,
                publicKey,
                privateKey,
            });
            await newClient.save();
            console.log(`[+] New user created: ${hwid}`);
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log(`[i] User already exists: ${hwid} aborting...`);
            return false;
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('[!] Error in createClient:', error.message);
        return false;
    }
};
```

Finally, here is my test script:

```js
import { connectToDatabase, createClient, disconnectFromDatabase } from './utils/db.js';

const databaseURL = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/wbs_clients';

const testCreateClient = async () => {
    try {
        await connectToDatabase(databaseURL);
        const result = await createClient('testHWID', '127.0.0.1');
        if (result) {
            const createdClient = await Client.findOne({ hwid: 'testHWID' });
            console.log('[i] Client details:', createdClient);
        } else {
            console.log('[i] createClient failed');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('[!] Error in testCreateClient:', error.message);
    } finally {
        await disconnectFromDatabase();
    }
};
testCreateClient();
```

Here's what I get on the first run:

```bash
D:\WMP\Training\WBS-C2>node .\src\test.js
Debugger attached.
[i] Connected to MongoDB at: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/wbs_clients
[+] New user created: testHWID
[!] Error in testCreateClient: Client is not defined
[i] Disconnected from MongoDB
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

However, I've noticed on `MongoDB Compass` that the "testHWID" client has been created.

Can you help me retrieve and display the information stored in my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `Client` into the test script. It's available to the `createClient` function because you imported it in `db.js` but it was never exported from that file.

```js
import { connectToDatabase, createClient, disconnectFromDatabase } from './utils/db.js';
import Client from '../models/Client.js'; //< Add this
//...
//...
```